# Storing a Range object in a Variant

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim not_rng As Variant
    Set rng = Sheets("Test").Range("A1:B2")
    Debug.Print TypeName(rng)
    not_rng = rng
    Debug.Print TypeName(not_rng)
End Sub
```

The code above prints

```
Range
Variant()
```

I would like it to print `Range, Variant`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input type changes if output not captured](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39442431/input-type-changes-if-output-not-captured)

Comment: @Alex, well, I wouldn't ask the same question twice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I was missing the `Set` keyword:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim not_rng As Variant
    Set rng = Sheets("Test").Range("A1:B2")
    Debug.Print TypeName(rng)
    Set not_rng = rng
    Debug.Print TypeName(not_rng)
End Sub
```

Now it prints

```
Range
Range
```

which makes more sense.