# Input type changes if output not captured

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a function that does different things depending on the type of the input. Unfortunately, I've found that the type of the *input* depends on whether the *output* is captured or not.

```
Function what_type(x As Variant) As String
    Debug.Print TypeName(x)
    what_type = TypeName(x)
End Function

Sub range_test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("Test").Range("F28:G28")
    what_type (rng)
    Debug.Print what_type(rng)
End Sub
```

Running `range_test` prints

```
Variant()
Range
Range
```

which is not what I'd expect.

What is the rationale for this peculiar behaviour/what's the big picture here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first call of `what_type`, you have passed a parameter of `(rng)`, i.e. the values of `rng` as a Variant array.  This results in the Debug.Print displaying `Variant()`.

In your second call of `what_type`, you have passed a parameter of `rng`, i.e. the actual range object.  This results in the Debug.Print displaying `Range`, and that being passed back as the result, which then is again Debug.Printed.

If your first call was changed to just

```
what_type rng
```

it, too, would display `Range` as the variable type.

Or if your second call was changed to

```
Debug.Print what_type((rng))
```

it would display `Variant()` both inside the function and as the returned result.

P.S.  It is always a bad idea to invoke a function using the syntax for a subroutine.  A function returns a value (or, at least, it **should**) and it is always a good idea to dispose of that returned value in some way, be that an assignment to a variable, or passing it to another function/subroutine.